# PrimeFaces (selectoneMenu,comandlink and inplace) not working on chromium browser

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces (selectoneMenu,comandlink and inplace) not working on chromium browser
Please see below code and let me know what I am doing wrong here. selectOneMenu is just showing first element (on clicking dropown doesn't show all) commondlink and inplace is also not working. firefox 17.0.1 its working fine but not in 19.0.2. it's very strange.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


       <h:head>
          <title>Facelet Title</title>
       </h:head>
       <h:body>

          <h:outputText value="Basic Usage: " />

          <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="formpanel" rowClasses="prop" columnClasses="name,value,message">
             <h:outputLabel for="selectLocation">Location:</h:outputLabel>
             <h:form>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectLocation" value="#{assetManager.currentLocation}">
                   <f:selectItems value="#{assetManager.selectItemManagedLocations}" />
                      <p:ajax update=":locationform:assetlist" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
             </h:form>

          </h:panelGrid>

       <h:form id ="locationform">
             <p:dataTable emptyMessage="No assets for branch."
                          value="#{assetManager.assetsByLocation}" var="a" styleClass="workflowtable" 
                          id="assetlist" >
                <f:facet name="header" >
                   Assets for #{assetManager.currentLocationName}
                </f:facet>

             <p:column id="lftype" width="95px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Type"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{a.model.make.type.description}"></h:outputText>
             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfmake" width="110px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Make"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{a.model.make.description}"></h:outputText>
             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfmodel" width="110px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Model"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{a.model.description}"></h:outputText>
             </p:column>

             <p:column id="lfserialNo" width="110px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Serial No"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{a.serialNo}"></h:outputText>
             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfstatus" width="90px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Status"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>


                   <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{a.status}" style="width: 60px;" >
                      <f:selectItems value="#{assetManager.assetStatuses}" />
                      <p:ajax listener="#{assetManager.updateStatus(a)}" />
                   </p:selectOneMenu>


             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfaddedby" width="100px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Added By"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{assetHelper.getAddLog(a) eq null}" value="Unknown"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{assetHelper.getAddLog(a) ne null}" value="#{assetHelper.getAddLog(a).employeeName}"></h:outputText>
             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfaction" width="50px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Action"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>


                   <p:commandLink style="margin-right:20px;"  action="/asset/edit.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">  
                      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{maintenanceManager.asset}" value="#{a}" />
                      <h:graphicImage value="/images/EditSmall.png" />
                   </p:commandLink>  


             </p:column>


             <p:column id="lfcomments" width="210px" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Comments"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>

                   <p:inplace id="ajaxCommentsInplace" editor="true" emptyLabel="Click here to add comments">
                      <p:inputText value="#{a.comments}"
                                   required="false" label="text" id ="commentsText"/>
                      <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{assetManager.updateStatus(a)}" />

                   </p:inplace>

             </p:column>


          </p:dataTable>
       </h:form>
       </h:body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include all your components in view, form hierarchy. i.e,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view>
        <h:head />
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:somecomponentofyourchoice>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

That must help.

Comment: Thanks. I added it but the problem was not with prime faces. Its resolved.Thanks